# problems with Email JS + AntD

Tags: reactjs, email, antd

Recently faced a problem. I created a form using AntD to send emails using the EmailJs library. The problem is that the  component from AntD does not send anything to email, but if you use just  then everything is fine. Other components like  are fine. Maybe someone knows how to fix this?

Here is my "code"

```
const ContactUs = (props) => {

function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('There is a userID and serverID that I do not want to show')
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });
    e.target.reset()
}


return (
    <Content style={{margin: '0 16px'}}>
        <Breadcrumb style={{margin: '16px 0'}}>
            <Breadcrumb.Item> </Breadcrumb.Item>
        </Breadcrumb>
        <div className="site-layout-background" style={{padding: 24, minHeight: 360}}>
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={sendEmail}>
                    <div >
                        <Input placeholder="Email" name={"email"} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Input placeholder="Full name" name={"full_name"}   />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Select name="course_level" defaultValue="Course Level"  >
                            <Option value="a1">A1</Option>
                            <Option value="a2">A2</Option>
                            <Option value="b1">B1</Option>
                            <Option value="b2">B2</Option>
                        </Select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Input placeholder="Basic usage" name={"telephone"}  />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Input placeholder="Basic usage" name={"add_inform"}  />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{marginRight: "10px"}}>
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Content>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Email-js requires 4 arguments as given in the official document:

```
emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
```

The third argument is expected to be the HTML form element (the form you are working with) . You can achieve this by useRef hook in react.

```html
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
const ContactUs = (props) => {
const form=useRef();
function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm(
        'your_service_id',
        'your_template_id',
        form.current,
        'your_public_key'
      )
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });
    e.target.reset()
}
  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      ....
    </form>
  )
 }
 export default ContactUs;
```